# Unity Cloud Build: Corrupted reffernces. Reimport All Assets possible?

Tags: unity

When references in scenes or prefabs are missing, usually a reimport all fixes all issues. But when those problems occur in a cloud build that get's its data from a git repository the solution seems much harder. The [AssetDatabase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html) API allows for a reimport in a prebuild script:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;

class Reimporter : IPreprocessBuildWithReport {

    public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }
    public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildReport report) {
        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset("Assets", ImportAssetOptions.ImportRecursive);
    }
}
```

But the `UnityEditor` libary isn't accessible in a cloud build.
Is there a way to fix missing references in a cloud build or trigger a reimport via a pre build script or something similar?

PS: Local builds after a fresh checkout of the github project do not have this issue, and only Cloud builds suffer from these missing references. Maybe someone knows the root of the issue and how to overcome it, so that none of these hacky solutions would be required.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple: Next to the the regular "build" button in the start build dropdown there's a "clean build". This fixed all of our problems.

It seemes to have the same effect as a local "reimport all".

The solution was found [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-cloud-build-breaks-local-build-fine.365624/).